# isomorphic cohomology rings for the spaces $(S^1 \times \mathbb{C}P^{\infty})/(S^1 \times *)$ and $(S^3 \times \mathbb{C}P^{\infty})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I need to show that the spaces $(S^1 \times \mathbb{C}P^{\infty})/(S^1 \times *)$ and $(S^3 \times \mathbb{C}P^{\infty})$ have isomorphic cohomology rings.

any ideas ..... thanx!

Comment: Do you know how to compute either one of the two cohomology rings?

Comment: yes, using Kunneth thm, I did the solution, thank you.

Comment: Then please do write an answer!